# How to delete all characters before a certain design notepad++?

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

Me need to save table `<table class="tftable" border="1">   information  </table>`  . Remove other information before and after.

How to implement this is better. There are about 90,000 pages of this kind. The structure they all have the same. Information in the tables is different.

```
<h1>jnouaoh098hwgv 03g030h </h1>
<div class="list-posts">
  <div class="post-item">
    <div class="text">
      <p>iuah8n987hauuih uouahou paniuaugpiubrebg940wbunv9wh0uvnw95n 8h 8hgu 0hu8gh</p>
      <h2>594w81grghiwuehuwn</h2>

      <table class="tftable" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>aiurh8n 7a8 </th>
          <th>aihnguaw </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>uuhqncm998m4</td>
          <td>от 11 000 wg.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>shshrs</td>
          <td>оsuhrguhousehrg</td>
        </tr>
          <td>sre e</td>
          <td>от 500 fs.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rseh sreh</td>
          <td>от 400 ewf.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ge ge</td>
          <td>от 350 gw.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>eg</td>
          <td>ge gew</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
        <h5>aweaweh hahrhrhhrrrrrrrrrrarh
          <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 598229929</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 5191iuhyg7g</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 56cn847n9qc849</li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: replace `.*(\<table class="tftable" border="1"\>.*\<\/table\>?).*` with \1 ... play around with it a little got get just what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all ocurrences of `<table>`, `<\table>` **and the contents between this tags**.
You can use this *Regex* in the search pattern:

```
.*?(<table(.*)<\/table>).*
```

And this token in the substitution field:

```
\1
```

Don't forget to check `true` for the options:

```
Regular Expressions

. Matches new line
```

Like this image:

[image: Notepad++ Screenshot]